# How can I make a random level selection system in my game?

Tags: batch-file, random, reset

What I thought up:

```sh
:TransL
cls
set num=%random% %%5
if %num% == 1 goto Level1
if %num% == 2 goto Level2
if %num% == 3 goto Level3
if %num% == 4 goto Level4
if %num% == 5 goto Level5
```

How can I reset it every time I goto `TransL` so a new random level will select instead of it going to the same level over and over again?

Answer (score 4):

you need to use the `/a` switch in your `set` command, additionally, no need to do `if` each time:

```
:TransL
cls
set /a num=%random% %%5+1
goto level%num%
```